# Why can I select all radio buttons in an Android CheckedList?

Tags: android, listview, android-radiobutton

I'm very, very new to Android, so I'm following tutorials and examples everywhere. First I was told the user needs to select multiple files, so I created this list view, and selection worked as expected, with check boxes to the left of each list item:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:id="@+id/checked_text_view"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text=""
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" />
```

But then I was told the user must only select one file, so I changed the `android:drawableLeft` property to `android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle`

And as expected, I instead got radio buttons to the left of each list item. But, I can select multiple radio buttons. I'm sure I have to group them somehow, but can't find a reliable resource on how to do it. Can I do it, or must I rely on a click event to clear all the other radio buttons when a new one is clicked. And that really smells bad.

**NOTE:** I have solved the problem using this code, but I will leave the question open to give someone a chance to answer, and hopefully educate me a bit more.

Comment: To group them you can use: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html

Comment: Doesn't work, as they are each inside their own `CheckedTextView`, so they remain separate.

Comment: Well checked textView as the name suggest is just check. You are just setting it the radio drawable which does not cary functionality. Ether rewrite it to use RadioGroup, or in the click event clear all the others, as you suggested

Comment: @X3Btel I used this technique and it works nicely, so far: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/01/08/single-selection-listview-in-android/

Comment: You are welcome to answer your own question below and accept it yourself

Comment: @ProfK Sorry, i missed that your view is inside ListView, in that case the solution you found is the right one.